# Yelp API missing an API key error while migrating

Tags: api, yelp

I'm getting this error when I am doing `rake db:migrate`.

> Yelp::Error::MissingAPIKeys: You're missing an API key
>   /Users/subhajit/grub_food/config/initializers/yelp.rb:1:in `'

My application.yml is containing all API keys.

Answer (score 0):

There are two case possible :
**1st Case** 
You didnot added your `Yelp API Keys` in your `config/yelp.rb` (new generated) file as below

```
Yelp.client.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'myconsumerkey'
  config.consumer_secret = 'consumersecretkey'
  config.token = 'mytokenkey'
  config.token_secret = 'tokensecret'
end
```

To get these keys go to [Yelp API developer console](https://www.yelp.com/developers/manage_api_keys) .

**2nd Case :** 
 You may not restarted your server after including keys in your `config/yelp.rb` file